# How to write nested formatting inside a table

Tags: tables

I'm learning how to build tables and I am having issues formatting within the table. I'm attempting to use Italics and subscripting together, and it works outside of the table but within the table it won't compile. In the following code, lines 5 and 7 both provide the proper formatting, however neither compiles inside the table.

If it's possible to do this with only one command, I would still prefer to know how to use subscripts and italic together inside a table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[k_{pi}\]
{\itshape kpi}
{\itshape \[k_{pi}\]}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{ZIP load parameters}
    \label{tab:table 12}
    \begin{tabular}{| c | l | c |}
\hline       
Variable & Description & Unit \\ 
\hline \hline

{\itshape kpi} or {\itshape pi0}

& Active current & \% or pu \\ 

{\itshape kpi} or {\itshape pp0} & Active power & \% or pu \\ 
{\itshape kpz} or {\itshape pz0} & Conductance & \% or pu \\ 
{\itshape kqi} or {\itshape qi0} & Reactive current & \% or pu \\ 
{\itshape kqp} or {\itshape qp0} & Reactive power & \% or pu \\ 
{\itshape kqz} or {\itshape qz0} & Susceptance & \% or pu \\ 
\hline

    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
```

I'm trying to match Table 14.2 from Power Systems Modeling by Milano page 316 incase someone wants to know what I'm attempting to recreate.

Comment: The underscore `_` is for subscripts in _math mode_. For text subscripts use `\textsubscript`. If `k_{pi}` has to be in math mode then use `$...$` (inline math) instead of `\[...\]` (display math).

Comment: This solves it. I really wish something on googles front page made this distinction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

- `\itshape` doesn't set \math` environment, which is needed to write  indices, for this you  should vrite in your table for example

```
$k_{pi} or $p_{p0}$ & Active power & \% or $p_u$ \\
```

- In stead above way to vrite table contents, you can introduce new columns, which are in math mode, for math expression in table as done in MWE (Min imal Working Example) below
- That some column is in math mode, you should replace for example `r` with `>{$}r<{$}`. For this you need load package `array` in document preamble.
- to not repeat the same text in column, you can do this with `c<{or}` as is done in MWE below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
\caption{ZIP load parameters}
\label{tab:table 12}
\begin{tabular}{| >{$}r<{$} @{\ }  c<{or} @{\ } >{$}l<{$} 
                |    l 
                | c<{\% or} @{\ }>{$}l<{$} |}
    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Variable}
                        & Description       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Unit} \\
    \hline \hline
k_pi && p_{i0} & Active current    && p_u   \\
k_pi && p_{p0} & Active power      && p_u   \\
k_pi && p_{z0} & Conductance       && p_u   \\
k_pi && q_{i0} & Reactive current  && p_u   \\
k_pi && q_{p0} & Reactive power    && p_u   \\
k_pi && q_{z0} & Susceptance       && p_u   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: are there 2 extra columns

Comment: @jsbibra, you are right! a copy/past error ;-(. Corrected now